# Django Query Works on python shell but it didnt work in template and forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i tried the same code on forms in shell. the code working like i want.
but when it deploy from Forms.py to html template instead become `[models_name].objects.all()`

in forms.py

```
main_page_choices = MainPage.objects.filter(parent_check=2).values_list('id', 'page_link')
main_page_choices_list = []

for main_page in main_page_choices:
    main_page_choices_list.append(main_page)

class AdminCreateSubPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SubPage
        fields = (
            'sub_title', 'sub_title_tag', 'sub_page_link', 'body', 'parent_page', 'meta_keyword', 'meta_description')

        widgets = {
            'sub_title': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'sub_title', 'onchange': 'autotypelink()'}),
            'sub_title_tag': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'sub_title_tag'}),
            'sub_page_link': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'sub_page_link'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'body'}),
            'parent_page': forms.Select(choices=main_page_choices_list, attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'parent_page'}),
            'meta_keyword': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'meta_keyword', 'rows': '4'}),
            'meta_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'meta_description', 'rows': '4'}),
        }
```

my models.py

```
class MainPage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    page_link = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True,
                         config_name='special',
                         external_plugin_resources=[
                             ('youtube',
                              '/static/ckeditor_plugins/youtube/youtube/',
                              'plugin.js'),
                         ]
                         )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default="", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_check = models.ForeignKey(ParentCheck, default="", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meta_description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    meta_keyword = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.page_link

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("main-list-admin")



class SubPage(models.Model):
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_page_link = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True,
                         config_name='special',
                         external_plugin_resources=[
                             ('youtube',
                              '/static/ckeditor_plugins/youtube/youtube/',
                              'plugin.js'),
                         ]
                         )
    parent_page = models.ForeignKey(MainPage, default="", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meta_description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    meta_keyword = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.page_link)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('admin-home')
```

in html template i just use

```
{% csrf_token %}
{% form.media %}
{% form.as_p %}
```

the result i want is like on python shell

```
>>> main_page_choices = MainPage.objects.filter(parent_check=2).values_list('id', 'page_link')
>>> main_page_choices_list = []
>>> for main_page in main_page_choices:
...     main_page_choices_list.append(main_page)
...
>>> print(main_page_choices_list)
[(2, 'cara-berjualan-online')]
>>>
```

`[(2, 'cara-berjualan-online')]` => This is I want but I didnt get in html

So in html the framework show all

[image: see the result here]

Could you explain to me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that returns the choice list and pass that function as choices.

```
def get_main_page_choices_list():
    main_page_choices = MainPage.objects.filter(parent_check=2).values_list('id', 'page_link')
    main_page_choices_list = []
    for main_page in main_page_choices:
        main_page_choices_list.append(main_page)
    return main_page_choices_list
```

Then in form,

```
...
forms.Select(choices=get_main_page_choices_list, attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'parent_page'}),
...
```

**Edit:**
Try overriding the **init** method to set choices again

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    choices = get_main_page_choices_list()
    self.fields['parent_page'].choices = choices 
    self.fields['parent_page'].widget.choices = choices
```

Comment: There is no error message, but the result still same like the screenshot

Comment: Please try the updated solution (Overriding `__init__`)

Comment: pardon? 
i dont get it how to overriding `__init__`

Comment: Add that method to your ModelForm